# Typescript: Function overload resolution for number | ArrayBuffer

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

While trying to integrate [WebGL2 typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webgl2%20WebGL2%20typings) into our project I've encountered a type error which I was able to boil down to the following [snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20WebGL2RenderingContext%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bufferData(target%3A%20number%2C%20size%3A%20number%2C%20usage%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bufferData(target%3A%20number%2C%20srcData%3A%20ArrayBuffer%2C%20usage%3A%20number)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(gl%3A%20WebGL2RenderingContext%2C%20sizeOrData%3A%20number%20%7C%20ArrayBuffer)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20gl.bufferData(0%2C%20sizeOrData%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F**%0D%0A%20*%20Error%20on%20line%207%3A%0D%0A%20*%20%0D%0A%20*%20Argument%20of%20type%20'number%20%7C%20ArrayBuffer'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'ArrayBuffer'.%0D%0A%20%20%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'ArrayBuffer'.%0D%0A%20*%2F):

```
interface WebGL2RenderingContext {
  bufferData(target: number, size: number, usage: number): void;
  bufferData(target: number, srcData: ArrayBuffer, usage: number): void;
}

function test(gl: WebGL2RenderingContext, sizeOrData: number|ArrayBuffer){
  gl.bufferData(0, sizeOrData, 0);
}
```

which results in the following compilation error:

> Argument of type 'number | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer'.

As far as I can tell this should be valid code, but I'm not entirely sure whether I've encountered a bug in TS, incorrect typings or whether the error is on my end after all. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because [overloads do not resolve based on union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).  Neither overload matches the `number|ArrayBuffer` type for the second parameter, and the compiler doesn't understand that the pair of overloads can be merged. There are no immediate plans to address this, although it is recognized as a pain point.

That means the WebGL2 typings for `bufferData()` aren't exactly *incorrect*, but they're not great.  The TypeScript Handbook "Do's and Don'ts" page specifically lists this as a ["Don't"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#use-union-types).  Since the signatures differ only by the type of one argument, it would be better to use a union type, like this:

```
interface WebGL2RenderingContext {
  bufferData(target: number, sizeOrData: number | ArrayBuffer, usage: number): void;
}
```

Then your code would not throw an error.  In lieu of contributing this definition back upstream, you could just locally add it yourself to your own code via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) and everything will work for you.

Hope that helps; good luck!